# Images gone after configure IIS , how to use web client

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, iis, webclient

I recently created a website and I run it on localhost using IIS, but my image icons and background images (which is stored in the local folder of the web project itself) are gone. How can I have them back? Also how do I use web client to retrieve domain path like "C:/projects/projects123/" so when in a separate WPF application I can retrieve it by calling the domain path without manually hard code the full path to retrieve something from the local folder of the web project.

Codes for Images :

```
<td width = "30%"><asp:ImageButton ID="imgPrepositions" runat="server" 
        ImageUrl="Images/MenuIcons/Preposition.png" width = "100px" 
        onclick="imgPrepositions_Click" ToolTip="Preposition" Height="100px"/></td>
```

On right click on the image it shows :

[image]

Now because I publish it, the folder became iStellarMobile_deploy, some of my codes are not working because of the directory. Is there any way to solve it? changing the path in the code is not the way to solve it I guess.

Comment: can you post the code that displays the images?

Comment: Right click on the images that are gone and view properties, what path do they have?

Comment: Is `iStellarMobile_deploy` your virtual directory name or no?

Comment: Yes virtual directory

Comment: I see you are using Firefox, do you have Firebug installed? If so, when you run the app with the Firebug console open, do you get a specific HTTP error for the images?

Comment: , i can click on those images , just that the images are gone . Sorry but how do i check for error using firebug? Just installed FireBug after i see your comment , how do i check for error with it ?

Comment: @user2376998 - in the top right hand corner of Firefox is a little icon that looks like a bug, hover over it and it should say Firebug version whatever is deactivated, click it activate Firebug. Upon activating Firebug, a window should appear docked to the bottom of your browser with two sets of menus. Choose `Console` from the top menu and then navigate to your page where the images are missing. Upon the page loading look for any messages in red that indicate HTTP errors.

Comment: Oh i got it i click on the images , it doesn't prompt any error msg

Comment: There were no errors when just loading the page?

Comment: yeah no errors  . Is it because the directory have been changed to iStellarMobile_deploy instead of the original project directory?

Comment: How about changing imageurl to `ImageUrl="~/Images/MenuIcons/Preposition.png"`? What about permissions on the image?

Comment: Well that rules out a path problem, so it must be a permissions issue. What version of IIS are you using?

Comment: Does the application pool account have access to your `Images` directory?

Comment: Am i doing the right thing? because i publish my website in Visual Studio then i copy its link to IIS but the folder in the deployment doesn't consits of the images folder and stuffs

Comment: What physical folder is the iStellarMobile virtual directory pointing at? I am guessing it is right, because you did not see an HTTP 404 error in Firebug for the images, which you would have if the path was invalid.

Comment: virtual path of iStellarMobile pointing at /iStellarMobile_deploy

Comment: iStellarMobile_deploy is inside a folder C:\inetpub\wwwroot\iStellarMobile_deploy after i publish in visual studio .. then i copy its link to IIS

Comment: it's not pointing to the C or D drive of your machine?

Comment: Check the comment above yours , its actually C:\inetpub\wwwroot\iStellarMobile_deploy , but in the virtual path its only \iStellarMobile_deploy.

Comment: The image folder is not inside  C:\inetpub\wwwroot\iStellarMobile_deploy after i publish .

Comment: @MikeSmithDev Sory didn't see your comment , but how do i change my code in the deployment file?

Comment: @user2376998 make sure your image folder is "included in the project" by right clicking the folder in Solution Explorer. The "~" will be translated on the server to the proper path... just update your image references (on server controls) to start with "~/".